# Jquery class change stops working on the second function call

Tags: jquery, image, carousel

I'm working on creating a jquery carousel. This function slides the images to the left and changes their classes according to what position they have been moved to. (after you click a button called "increase"). It works the first time just as it should, removing the left image, changing the middle class to the left, and the right to the middle while adding a new image on the right and giving it the right position class. Here is the fiddle if you want to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/25/

The second time the function gets called, everything gets messed up. A new image is appended but it has 0 opacity, and the class is .right_slot. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```
function slide_img_left() {

        var imgs = imgArr.length;
        a++;
        if (a >= imgs) {
            a = 0;
        }

        b = a - 1;
        c = a + 1;

        if (b < 0) {
            b = imgs - 1;
        }
        if (c >= imgs) {
            c = 0;
        }

        var left = $('.left_slot'); var middle = $('.middle_slot'); var right = $('.right_slot');
        var newImg = imgArr[c][0];
        left.animate({
            opacity: 0,
            left: '-=50px'
        }, 300, function() {
            left.remove();
        });


        middle.animate({
            left: '-=50px'
        }, 300, function() {
            middle.attr('class', 'left_slot');
            right.attr('class', 'middle_slot');
        });

        right.animate({
            left: '-=50px'
        }, 300, function(){
            $("#basic_div").append(newImg);
            newImg.attr('class', 'right_slot'); 
        });

        $("#varsDiv").html(" var b = " + b + " var a = " + a + " var c = " + c);

    }
```

Comment: Can't really tell what's going on there with `a` `b` `c` ...

Comment: don't worry about that part... they control the array that the images are stored in.They come into effect when appending the new image such as in the case of above where it says var newImg = imgArr[c][0];

Comment: MMm... don't know it seems like the might be a better way to do that. Can you post your array?

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way but I'm a noob at jquery so this is what I got so far. Please see the fiddle for the array. It is the four images at the top above the buttons. I know the images are there inside the array because I've used alerts to show me the paths. They are in there.

Comment: I'm just trying to loop through the array and cycle through those four images is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should `.clone()` your images or revert the changes you make to their styles.

  ```
  $("#basic_div").append(imgArr[b].clone());
  $("#basic_div").append(imgArr[a].clone());
  $("#basic_div").append(imgArr[c].clone());
  ...
  function slide_img_left() {
    ...
    var newImg = imgArr[c].clone();
    ...
  }
  ```
- Moving `left_slot` to the left and hiding it is just screwing your layout. `middle_slot` gets out of sight.

This is [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2C8fy/) for the increase function with a slightly different fade out effect.

Comment: Dude, you are my personal hero... You solved like three of the problems I was having all at once. Thanks man! I didn't know about .clone